# 403 Forbidden Error on CodeIgnitor web app

Tags: codeigniter, linkedin-api

[image: Error message]
[Permission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F17IV.jpg)

I'm trying to allow my app to work be able to allow users to login via LinkedIn, however i keep getting the `403 Forbidden Error` as shown in the screenshot.
Hopefully someone can advise.

Comment: Where is your code?  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says that you do not have enough permission to use LinkedIn API. You need to request permissions from linkedin.

Comment: Hi Lalit, thank you for your prompt reply, i think i have the necessary permission(see new attached image called - permission page) . Not sure i am missing out anything else?

Comment: In that case, you should contact **Linkedin** support for your problem. You can compose a mail and define your problem.

Comment: Hi Lilat, i tried contacting them previously. This was their reply to me :
In an effort to boost support for our developer community, we moved our online support forum from the Developers site to StackOverflow. The older forums on the Developers site will be available for reference in a read-only state.
 
Before asking LinkedIn API-related questions at StackOverflow, be sure to:
•  Tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them.
•  Read StackOverflow's How to Ask Good Questions guide.
•  StackOverflow is for technical questions and answers only.

Comment: You can't get any answer then you can see the following GitHub repository. It's a working code. https://github.com/lcdhakar87/linkedin-login-with-OAuth2. i hope this can help you

Comment: Hi lalit, okay let me try and revert :)